# Immutable data structures and concurrency

Tags: c#, concurrency, immutability

I'm trying to understand how using immutable data structures in concurrent programming can obviate the need for locking. I've read a few things on the web but haven't seen any concrete examples yet.

For example, let's say we have some code (C#) that uses lock(s) around a `Dictionary< string, object>` does this:

```
class Cache
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    object Get(string key, Func<object> expensiveFn)
    {
        if (!_cache.ContainsKey("key"))
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!_cache.ContainsKey("key"))
                    _cache["key"] = expensiveFn();
            }
        }
        return _cache["key"];
    }
}
```

How would that look if `_cache` was immutable? Would it be possible to remove the `lock` and also ensure `expensiveFn` isn't called more than once?

Comment: Why are you not just using `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: How would doing that prevent expensiveFn being invoked twice?

Comment: because `ConcurrentDictionary` already has a method that does exactly what your method does for `Dictionary`, except it's efficiently tuned by MS, and has an underlying storage structure that supports more efficient multithreaded access.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how using immutable data structures simplifies concurrent programming and removes the need for locks. Not sure how ConcurrentDictionary helps with that

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but it's almost certainly the best solution to your problem.  That's why I posted a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: Ok cool. My problem isn't that I'm trying to create a cache and have it work across threads, my problem is that I've read a bunch of stuff online about how immutable data structures are awesome for handling concurrency. Sounds good in theory but I would love to see some real world examples.

Comment: @Servy I think his point is that this particular piece of code isn't part of a solution to a real-world problem, he's just trying to understand the theory behind how using immutable data structures alters how you do concurrency. Using a ConcurrentDictionary is a perfectly valid solution to a real-world problem but it doesn't help with his understanding of this particular issue.

Comment: I note that the code you have here is very dangerous. You are calling an *arbitrary* function inside a lock; what if that function itself takes out a lock?  Suppose that lock is already held on another thread, in code that is itself trying to access your cache? This has deadlock written all over it.

Comment: Also, even leaving aside the deadlocking, *you've written a potentially incorrect implementation of double-check locking*. There are only a small number of "blessed" double-check locking patterns and the moment you deviate from any one of them, you are running in a world of the most terrible race conditions.  Do not elide locks unless you know the memory model inside out, and you have a demonstrated performance problem caused by the penalty of taking the lock.

Comment: If you wish to understand mechanisms that ensure that a given function only be called zero or one times to then have its result cached, carefully read the source code for `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: Eric, the code I have written isn't to solve a real problem. But would you care to explain why I've "written a potentially incorrect implementation of double-check locking"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer is that it doesn't, at least not completely.

Immutability only guarantees that another thread won't be able to modify the contents of your data structure while you are working with it.  Once you have an instance, that instance can never be modified, so you will always be safe reading it.  Any edits would require a copy of the instance to be made, but those copies wouldn't interfere directly with any instances already referenced.

There are still plenty of reasons why you would need locking and synchronization constructs in a multi-threaded application, even with immutable objects.  They mostly deal with timing related problems, such as race conditions, or controlling thread flow so that activities happen at the right time.  Immutable objects won't really do anything to help with these kinds of problems.

Immutability makes multi-threading *easier*, but it doesn't make it *easy*.

---

As far as your question about what an immutable dictionary would look like.  I'd have to say that in most cases it doesn't really make much sense, in your example, to even use an immutable dictionary.  Since it is being used as an "active" object that inherently changes as items are added and removed.  Even in a language designed around immutability, like F#, there are mutable objects for this purpose. See [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Collections#HashSet.3C.27T.3E.2C_and_Dictionary.3C.27TKey.2C_.27TValue.3E_Classes) for more details.  The immutable versions can be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Sets_and_Maps).

Comment: It's true that immutable data structures do not eliminate the need for locks. But I'd like to add that immutability sometimes enables you to replace locks with atomic operations like CAS ([Compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), see [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange(v=vs.110).aspx)) operations. Microsoft's immutable collections contains an `ImmutableInterlocked` class that has operations that appear to "modify" immutable lists, sets, dictionaries, etc. by using CAS operations.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea behind immutable data structures reducing (notice that I said "reducing," not "eliminating") the need for locking in concurrency is that every thread is working either on a local copy or against the immutable data structure so there's no need for locking (no thread can modify any other threads' data, just their own). Locking is only needed when several threads can modify the same mutable state at once because otherwise you have the possibility of "dirty reads" and other similar issues.

Comment: That is not quite true, it is not that each thread has it's own copy. it is the fact that you have a guarantee that the shared copy everyone is using will never be modified, if someone want's to modify it they need to make a new object and will no longer be using the shared copy.

Comment: Fair enough, that's more precise. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

One example of why immutable data is important:
Assume that you have a person object that is accessed by two different threads. 
If thread1 saves the person into a map (the person hash contains the person name), then another thread2 changes the person name.
Now thread1 will not be able to find this person inside the map while it is actually there!

If person was immutable, the references held by different threads will be different and thread1 will be able to find the person in the map even when user2 changes his name (since a new instance of person will be created).